# How to store the data's selected in a selectManyListbox into a List in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I am having a selectmanyListbox component in my JSF, now i want to store the selected data's into a List. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with every `UIInput` component, you just have to bind the `value` attribute with a property of the backing bean. Thus, so:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
    </h:selectManyListbox>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with the following in `Bean` class:

```
private List<String> selectedItems; // + getter + setter
private List<SelectItem> selectItems; // + getter only

public Bean() {
    // Fill select items during Bean initialization/construction.
    selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value1", "label1"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value2", "label2"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value3", "label3"));
}

public void submit() {
    // JSF has already put selected items in `selectedItems`.
    for (String selectedItem : selectedItems) {
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + selectedItem); // Prints value1, value2 and/or value3, depending on selection.
    }
}
```

If you want to use non-standard objects as `SelectItem` value (i.e. not a `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` for which EL has already builtin coercions), then you'll have to create a `Converter` for this. More details can be found in [this blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html).

Comment: When i assign a list to the values in selectManyListbox, I am getting the following warning. 

Cannot coerce type java.util.List to java.lang.String, java.lang.Short, java.lang.Character, 
 java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Float, 
 java.lang.Integer

Comment: Ignore and run it. Eclipse is a epic failure when it comes to JSF/JSP/EL validation.

Answer (score 2):

`<h:selectManyListBox value="#{managedBean.list}">`

and in the managed bean:

```
private List list;
```

(with the appropriate getter and setter, and if possible - using generics)